# JS wait for DOM changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a js file that modifies the DOM of a page, adds a nav menu. After that code is another function that modifies the resulting nav menu. The issue is unless I set a timeout to wait for the DOM to be changed I can not guarantee the final code will work as intended. Is there a more guaranteed method of invoking this final code (a 2nd DOM manipulation dependent on the 1st completing) than setTimeout()?

edit 1:
function being called

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        // do stuff;
    });
```

Comment: is your code wrapped in a self invoked function? meaning `(function(){// code here})();`

Comment: You'll need to show some code. To me it sounds like you're structuring your JS poorly or not using the appropriate tools for queuing your modifications to execute in the correct order.

Comment: It's usually as simple as using a `callback`.

Comment: You almost certainly want to emit an event or use a callback and structure your code accordingly.

Comment: Use a `callback` function.

Comment: see: **[call back functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/Using_js-ctypes/Declaring_and_Using_Callbacks)**

Comment: Yep call back s the way I would: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/Using_js-ctypes/Declaring_and_Using_Callbacks

Comment: Finish your modifications and then append the result to DOM or use a callback function as it was mentioned in previous comments. Anyway it's looking like your code should be refactored in some more logical way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your code, I can't tell exactly what you are trying to do. Based on what I can understand, you can create a callback to run the next function or call the next function at the end of the first function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //do some stuff

    //call next function
    myfunc2()
}
```